# make UITableViewCell selection blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to have the UITableViewCell highlight gray then go back to white after a user has touched the UITableViewCell..

I can make it go gray but it stays gray until the user selects another cell...

this is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

 }
```

Comment: Do u want to do any work when clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For making it deselected, u can add this

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

**Edit 1**

Try changing it to

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.8;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

});
```

Comment: maybe because u call it ryt away when user selects row… try calling it after a delay lets say 0.5 seconds and see if it's buggy...

Comment: i have narrowed it down.. first cell click it dosnt blink but then if i try a second time it works.. where would I add the delay?

Comment: wow, thats a mint function however it dosnt work. (well it works but again I have to click the cell first then it works on the second click.. the animation is much slower now compaired to without your new function).. I am trying to hunt down the problem.

Comment: do u have anything above the UItableView in hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass your UITableViewCell and override the `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` method, in order to perform the behaviour that you want.
For example you can change the color of the cell background and then fire a timer after 0.5 secs to turn it t the original one.

Answer (score 1):

### [UPDATED]

Swift 3

```
        let delayInSeconds = 0.7;
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds * 1) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Meseery my version (Swift 5) became:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:**

Override this method on your custom cell inheriting from UITableViewCell, inside it you can do whatever you need to do. In this case, if selected, I am changing my custom view `containerView` to gray and immediately animating it back to white.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    guard selected else { return }
    containerView.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
        self?.containerView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```